# Openoffice 4 on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

How do I install the latest version of Apache openoffice on Ubuntu 13.10(kubuntu to be more precise) without uninstalling LibreOffice.

Yes I know LO is better for some reasons(I did my homework) but I want to install AOO for testing purposes.

Preferably with a regularly updated ppa.

Comment: The problem is even after installing it, trying to open it just results in libreoffice opening... For testing purposes, you will need something without Libreoffice (probably)

Comment: Yeah,but I remember there were some workarounds(can't find them now) even though those workarounds were for Ubuntu 12.04 and older versions of AOO.

Comment: I think it was last year I tried to get it to get it to work, and I may get round to trying to get it to work again at some point. You can download the package for it [here](http://www.openoffice.org/download/), and another way of doing it is available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apacheoo-deb/files/debian/) (for Debian - should work on Ubuntu), which says to do this: `deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/apacheoo-deb/debian wheezy main` and then you can install it using `apt-get`.

Comment: I did it the way wilf described it(with the repo).However it does not show in the kde launcher or in open with,I had to go all the way to /opt and find it there.Any way to fix that?

Comment: Can you open it using `openoffice`, or another command line command? If so you need to create a `.desktop` launcher file, which should be easy *(comment if you need help)*. [This](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=55886) as well.

Comment: Where did you find it in `/opt`, as I have been meaning to sort this for a while...

Answer (score 1):

You need to download a .tar.gz or .tgz version of LibreOffice or OpenOffice. Unzip or untar it, and copy that to /opt. Then open the folder and click on the executable to start the program. You can create a shortcut to your desktop. You can make this a normal link with proper icon if you want to.

The other application can be installed the normal way. You should use the /opt version for the least used. It won't be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I just conquered this same problem.

You must purge LibreOffice in order to use Apache OpenOffice. They just will not play together.

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
```

Next, download the archive of debs from the site: http://www.openoffice.org/download/

```
  cd Downloads
  tar -xvf Apache*
  cd en-US/DEBS/
```

Install the software:

```
  sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

Then the desktop integration:

```
  cd desktop-integration
  sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

Now you should have Apache OpenOffice in your standard LXDE/KDE/Gnome/Unity/etc launch menu

Comment: Yes,but how to have both at the same time.